# How to write a query to output columns from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, select

I have three regular table.

Table Author

| AuthorID | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex | Popov |
| 2 | Serg | Smit |
| 3 | John | Paulse |

Table NameStatie

| NameStatieID | NameStatie | URLStatie |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | POPULATION OF TRNA-DERIVED | /item001 |
| 2 | AGENT-BASED SIMULATION MODEL | /item002 |
| 3 | CHAGAS' DISEASE DIAGNOSIS: | /item003 |

Table KeyWord

| KeyWordID | NameKeyWord |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | VIRTUAL LEARNING ENVIRONMENT |
| 2 | EDUCATIONAL OBJECTIVES |
| 3 | ACADEMIC PROGRESS EVALUATION |

I have a linked table by id
Table Statie

| StatieID | NameStatieID | AuthorID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

The problem is that if I add a column with KeyWordID to the Statie table, the number of rows will increase several times according to the following formula: Row = a * k
where a is Author, k are keywords.

I decided to create another intermediate table to avoid unnecessary padding.

Table NameStatieAndKeyWord

| NameStatieAndKeyWordID | NameStatieID | KeyWordID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

Question. How to generate an sql query to get this result?

| NameStatie | KeyWords | Author |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POPULATION OF TRNA-DERIVED | VIRTUAL LEARNING ENVIRONMENT, ACADEMIC PROGRESS EVALUATION | Alex Popov, John Paulse |

P.S. Sorry for my English, I'm from another country and use a translator. I will be glad if you criticize me. I just started learning

I couldn't do it in any way, errors were constantly being issued, but I have such a request that works

```
SELECT NameStatie, group_concat(LastName || " " || FirstName || "", ", ") as "Authors"
FROM Statie
JOIN NameStatie ON Statie.NameStatieID = NameStatie.NameStatieID
JOIN Author ON Statie.AuthorID = Author.AuthorID
GROUP by NameStatie.NameStatieID
```

| NameStatie | Authors |
| --- | --- |
| POPULATION OF TRNA-DERIVED | Alex Popov, John Paulse |

Comment: Your precise question isn't clear. Please [edit] it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is on how to do a `GROUP_CONCAT` with `DISTINCT` values, as discussed on the following thread from SQLite Forum: https://sqlite.org/forum/info/221c2926f5e6f155.

Query:

```sql
SELECT
  NameStatie,
  REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT NameKeyWord), ',', ', ') AS KeyWords,
  REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Author), ',', ', ') AS Authors
FROM (
  SELECT
    NameStatie.NameStatie,
    KeyWord.NameKeyWord,
    FirstName || " " || LastName AS Author
  FROM Statie
  JOIN NameStatie ON Statie.NameStatieID = NameStatie.NameStatieID
  JOIN Author ON Author.AuthorID = Statie.AuthorID
  JOIN NameStatieAndKeyWord ON Statie.NameStatieID = NameStatieAndKeyWord.NameStatieID
  JOIN KeyWord ON NameStatieAndKeyWord.KeyWordID = KeyWord.KeyWordID
  WHERE NameStatie.NameStatieID = 1
) GROUP BY NameStatie;
```

Output:

| NameStatie | KeyWords | Authors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| POPULATION OF TRNA-DERIVED | VIRTUAL LEARNING ENVIRONMENT, ACADEMIC PROGRESS EVALUATION | Alex Popov, John Paulse |

Comment: Thank you very much! I haven't even heard of such a trick!

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like below :

```
SELECT ns.NameStatie
,x.Authors
,y.Keywords
FROM NameStatie ns
left outer join(select STRING_AGG(CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName), ', ') AS  Authors,s.NameStatieID from Statie s 
inner join Author a on a.AuthorID = s.AuthorID GROUP by s.NameStatieID) as x on x.NameStatieID=ns.NameStatieID
left outer join(select STRING_AGG(NameKeyWord, ', ') AS  Keywords,nk.NameStatieID from NameStatieAndKeyWord nk
inner join KeyWord k on k.KeyWordID=nk.KeyWordID GROUP by nk.NameStatieID) as y on y.NameStatieID=ns.NameStatieID
GROUP by ns.NameStatieID,ns.NameStatie,x.Authors,y.Keywords
order by ns.NameStatieID
```

Note : If and only if you are working on SQL Server 2017 or later versions, you can use built-in SQL Server Function STRING_AGG to create the comma delimited list.